# Put a loading property on Dropdown.Button using ant design

Tags: reactjs, button, state, dropdown, antd

i want to put a loading component when i click a Dropdown.Button my code show below:

```
                          <Dropdown.Button
                            type="primary" 
                            overlay = {userMenu}
                            icon={<DownOutlined />} 
                            onClick={() => this.myFync()}           
                            loading={this.state.myloader}               
                            >
                            Press me
                          </Dropdown.Button>
```

My problem is that when i press the button i get the exact error:

```
 Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `loading`.
```

So i have found this example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-antd-4-22-3-forked-rupn99?file=/demo.js), but they just put true or false state inside an array, so can anyone explain me why the simple

```
 this.state.myloader
```

that taking values true or false is not right?

Comment: How are you setting your `this.state.myloader`?

Comment: I am setting my state when the user click the button. I have an axios request and before axios i am making the state `true`  `this.setState({ myloader: true })` and after with the same way i am making my state `false` @Scratch'N'Purr